# Using return true or return false on a link with target blank in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, popup

I have a form that has `target="_blank"`on submit.

I want to validate the form however, prior to it launching the new window.  I could use window.open instead, but then it can be blocked by popup blockers.

The problem I'm having is the validation uses ajax and the time it takes to get the response for return false, is too long and it opens the new window.

```
 $('.submit').click(function(){
        $.post("/ajax/save/", { state: $('.state_field').val() },
            function(data) {
                if(data == 'false'){
                    alert('invalid state');
                                    return false;
                }else{

                    return true;
                }
            }
        );
  });
```

Would anyone have suggestions as how I can workaround this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You should probably use `$("form").submit(function() {})` because that also catches when somebody presses Enter in a textfield.)

What you could do is

1. Don't include the `target="_blank"` in the form
2. catch the submission and block it (preferably using `event.preventDefault();`)
3. do the ajax call for validation
4. from within the callback: add the `target="_blank"` and submit the form again (you could use a check like `$("form[target]").length == 1` to see if the form is being submitted for the second time.

While this all can make it work, you should think about validating the form right after the user enters data in each field, this will also improve the user experience a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I didn't quite do it this way, but it gave me the idea.  I just created a new form that had target="_blank" and the correct action url.  Then just submit that secondary form if the primary form is correct

Answer (score 0):

Use the `preventDefault` method of the `event` at the beginning of your click.

```
$('.submit').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
[...]
```

This will stop your form from submitting and is a better solution than using `return false;`.

If you need to do a redirect after the ajax call you can do that the standard way:

```
window.location.replace([url to redirect to]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Popup blockers block the new `window` if they are opened in `script execution context`. If the window is opened through user action then it is allowed. You can try to use `jQuery` `ajax` in `synchronous` mode this will solve your other part of the question because the function will not wait untill ajax response comes and you return true/false conditionally.

```
       $('.submit').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
              url:  "/ajax/save/", 
              type: "POST",
              async: false,
              data: { state: $('.state_field').val() },
              success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 'false'){
                        alert('invalid state');
                        return false;
                    }else{

                        return true;
                    }
                }
            );
      });
```